# How to mock handle.useTransaction in JDBI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a class with public method name process() which invoked a private method called processAandB().
In the method processAandB() we are using

```
handle.useTransaction(h -> {
   //calling processA and processB private methods
   processA(h)

   processB(h)

}) [JDBI handle]
```

In processA we are creating tasks(Callable) which are to be processed via executor service and same applies to processB.

I am writing a JUnit test case where I've mocked the Handle and called the process() method and the problem is control is not going inside handle.useTransaction().
I am not sure how to invoke useTransaction in such a way that it call the processA and processB method too.

I tried mocking transaction too but couldn't.
Not sure what is the approach I should follow here.

Comment: Would you mind to put actual code here, so that your Question would be clear!

Comment: The transaction processing is happening in your DB. If you want to test transaction handling, you need to use a DB, not a mock, in your test.